# Using Enumerable to make standard iterators available to modify iterators

Tags: ruby, iterator, inject

I am **Attempting** to Use the *Enumerable* mixin to make all the standard iterators available in my class named  NumberArray . From that I'm trying to use the inject iterator to get the average of odd numbers in the array .

My code looks like this

```
 class NumberArray
  include Enumerable
  def initialize
    @numbers = Array.new
  end
```

then @numbers array is then filled with 1000 numbers

and finally I'm trying to create my own inject iterator to get the average of the odd values.

```
def inject

    puts self.inject{|sum,x| sum = sum + x if sum mod 2 == 1}

    asum
  end
```

I am very new to Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just subclass Array and override methods you want:

```
class NumberArray < Array
  def inject
    odds = select(&:odd?)
    odds.inject(:+).to_f / odds.size
  end
end

a = NumberArray.new([1,2,3,4,5])
a.inject # => 3.0
```

If it makes any sense to do it this way is another thing, but that's what you asked :)

Answer (score 2):

Classes that use the `Enumerable` mixin *must* have an `each` method, which yields for each successive element.

Since your class `NumberArray` is backed by a normal array, you can use the array's `each` method:

```
class NumberArray
  # ...
  def each
    @numbers.each
  end
end
```

As for your `inject` method, when you call `self.inject`, it just calls the method you're currently in again. This is called recursion, and will cause a `SystemStackError` in this case. I also don't recommend redefining the `inject` method in `NumberArray`, because it will override the `Enumerable` implementation of `inject`.

I'd use a more descriptive method name like `odd_avg`:

```
def odd_avg
  odds = @numbers.select(&:odd?)
  odds.inject(:+).to_f / odds.size
end
```

The first line of this method gets all the odd elements from `@numbers` and puts it into `odds`. The next line first gets the sum of `odds`, then converts the sum to a float, then divides by the number of odds.